# Need advice on updating a database from a form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am not sure how to word the question because I don't really know what exactly I'm even asking for. Basically I have built a small sales portal that puts info in a database and then spits it back out in various ways. Occasionally the records need to be updated, but I need a way to update them from the web page where the records are displayed (without going to a completely different page) so that the sales people do not have to go into the database to change the records. I know how to use the UPDATE function with PHP, what I would like to do is have an "Edit" button at the end of each row and have the information become changeable when the button is clicked. What programming language would I need to do this in? How would that code be structured? I am really only familiar with PHP, HTML, and CSS.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to edit inline you'll need to know JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: like @j08691 said, a jquery or ajax based solution seems to be the cleaner way to get what you want. I recommend read the jquery `$.post` and `$.get` feature docummentation

Comment: Javascript a clean language, that’s funny… ;)

Comment: JavaScript is a clean language. Many languages are clean, until incompetent people come along and misuse it. Much like with everything in life.

Comment: I don't know what did `skp` and `N.B` mean by the word `clean` but I would say that `JavaScript` is the most `hackish` language I've seen ever, IMO.

Comment: no tool is bad until someone uses it wrong.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are both terrible languages, frankly.  There's no reason to involve JS in this:  HTML form submit via POST -> process POST information server side.  I would advise against having multiple forms on a single page, as it will only confuse the user.

Comment: @cimmanon all the reason in the world points to javascript even if is just to display the form, dont blame the meat if you dont know how to cook it well

Comment: @Pablo the type safety and security is where?  What happens when JS is disabled?  JS is supposed to be used as an enhancement, not a replacement to things that already work right out of the box (form submissions, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need javascript to handle the form fields the way you mentioned.

- Each record row wil have the original value and a hidden input
- Javascript will hide the original value and show the input
- You could either have a save button at the end of each record row or a master "save all" button". Having multiple at the end of each record will be easier but from a users point of view maybe a bit cumbersome.

Use AJAX to send the updated data to the server - this should be handled in the "save record" javascript function.

Then you'll need PHP or some other server side language to actually update the record.